# How do the Attack Boost bonuses from Foods and Elixirs work?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

When cooking 'Mighty' food or elixirs, they grant differing levels of Attack Boosts determined by the ingredients that are combined.

How much outgoing damage is added per level of the boost?

Comment: For reference, the intrepid young adventurer can verify this by donning the champions tunic and testing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I just tested this using the method suggested by @Seiyria.

These following results are gathered while wearing the Champions Tunic, and using each tier of food against the same enemy at full health.

```
+--------------------+----------+----+----+----+
|       Weapon       | Standard | T1 | T2 | T3 |
+--------------------+----------+----+----+----+
| Torch              |        2 |  2 |  2 |  3 |
| Woodcutters Axe    |        3 |  3 |  3 |  4 |
| Throwing Spear     |        6 |  7 |  7 |  9 |
| Iron Sledgehammer  |       12 | 14 | 15 | 18 |
| Guardian Sword     |       20 | 24 | 26 | 30 |
| Knights Broadsword |       26 | 31 | 33 | 39 |
| Guardian Sword+    |       30 | 36 | 39 | 45 |
| Guardian Sword++   |       40 | 48 | 52 | 60 |
| Ancient Battleaxe++|       60 | 72 | 78 | 90 |
+--------------------+----------+----+----+----+
```

As indicated by this data, the Percentual Increases are:

- Tier 1 - 20%
- Tier 2 - 30%
- Tier 3 - 50%

(after rounding)

Comment: What about multiple boosts? There is an armor which gives bonus attack strength. Donning that and then taking buff food... how does that scale?

Comment: The maximum damage boost stacks you can get appears to be 3 stacks, wearing the barbarian set simply is simply an alternative to consuming mighty food.

Comment: So if you're wearing all 3 pieces of the barbarian set, you get the maximum damage boost of 50%?

What about "proficiency" like with the ancient armor set. Does that count as "damage boost tier with only that type of item", or is it separate?

Answer (score 0):

Ancient armor proficiency bonus stacks with atk up food as they are different classes of buffs. Further, guardian weapons found from test of strength shrines have a native 30% dmg buff against guardians and the ancient weapons bought from the lab have 50% dmg against guardians.

So the ancient proficiency bonus of 80 on an ancient weapon for 50 plus the atk food bonus of 50 comes out to 180%. Guardians be wrecked.  Ancient arrows should always be shot from an ancient bow for this reason.

Comment: "Ancient arrows should always be shot from an ancient bow for this reason. " Actually if you hit a guardian (whatever type) with an ancient arrow in the eye, the guardian is one-shooted regardless of the bow used. A korok bow is very useful for this do to both the zoom and the very straight trajectory.