# What are all possible effects, and how they function?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Is there a list of all effects that can be applied on Link (Sneak+, Cold Resistance, Guardian Resistance, etc.) and how the more complex ones are applied (and if you can, how is the effect stronger depending on the number of stacks)?

To explain the second part of the question: Yeah Cold/Heat resistance is straightforward enough, but things like Guardian Resistance... Does it block like half guardian damage per stack? Make me less discoverable by guardians?

Comment: Related question for attack boosts: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302498/how-do-the-attack-boost-bonuses-from-foods-and-elixirs-work

Comment: Well I'm having the answer for one of them... but what about the rest of them?

Comment: We have the answer for defense here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304466/how-is-damage-reduction-from-armor-calculated

Comment: The one that intrigues me the most is really Guardian defense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First: Sorry, this question will always come back on top, it's gonna be edited a few time to put in more and more details.

**Damage Boost**

- Tier 1 - +20%
- Tier 2 - +30%
- Tier 3 - +50%

**Armor Boost**

- Tier 1 - +4 armor (1 hearts)
- Tier 2 - +12 armor (3 hearts)
- Tier 3 - +24 armor (6 hearts)

**Heat and Cold reduction:**

- 2 tiers - 1 tier gives a little bit of protection, 2nd tier is needed for extreme environments (top of mountains or middle of desert). Does not count for catching fire. (Goron mountain)

**Fire protection:**

- 2 tiers, needed for how high up death mountain you are. You wont catch fire close to lava.

**Guardian Protection:**

- 3 tiers, *effect unknown, probably Armor Boost against Guardians*

**Ancient Proficiency:**

- 1 tier, grants +80% damage bonus when using Guardian or Ancient weapons

**Sneak +:**

- 3 tiers, each tier reduces the distance at which ennemies can detect/spot you

**Speed +:**

- 3 tiers, Boost movement speed. *Amounts unknown, but seems glider/climb speed is unaffected.*

**Climb Speed +:**

- 3 tiers, Boost climb speed. *Amounts unknown.*

**Lightning Protection**

- 1 tier, grants immunity to Lightning, as well as ignoring the shock effects of electric attacks (but not the damage). It prevents the stun and weapon drops. [Thanks SGR!]

**Lightning Resistance**

- todo

**Swim Speed Up**

- X Tiers, makes you swim faster.

**Sand/Snow movement**

- 1 tier, lets you move as fast as on regular land in snow/sand

Comment: I don't really have the time or energy to put out a detailed enough answer to fit my personal standards, but you're missing a couple of effects.  Lightning protection, swimming, sand/snow movement. Then of course there's set bonuses which are directly related. And there's other equipment/sets that have other potential effects such as monster masks, dark clothes, radiant clothes. There's a lot to unpack here.

Comment: yeah i did put an answer that would be edited the more and more info we have, since if nobody did it, it would seem the question would have stayed answerless (I did put a bounty and nothing came of it)

Comment: And I think that set bonuses are out of the intended scop of the question

Comment: Should tier 3 armour be 6 hearts?

Comment: Lightning Protection is 1 tier and grants immunity to Lightning, as well as ignoring the shock effects of electric attacks (but not the damage)

Comment: keep in mind lightning protection is different from both _resistance_ and _shockproof_ (rubber set bonus)

Comment: Shockproof is identical to Lightning Protection effect-wise. There's also Burnproof and Frostproof, which are basically the same for other elemental effects.